# Delete blank rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete rows based on multiple criteria spread across multiple columns. Essentially, I have a list of names in column A, and a list of plans across row 1.

[image]

The issue is, sometimes there is a plan 1, sometimes there is a plan 2, and sometimes there are both, as in the above picture. The plans also change which column they are in.

I am trying to write some vba to to see if either of those plans exist in the header, and if one or both of them do exist, delete the row where a person is blank in both. In the picture above, the row with "Barry Bonds" would need to be deleted.

So far I have the method to delete blanks in one column, but I don't know how to do it for more than one column, or to switch between plan names (i.e. Plan 1 or Plan 2).

```
Sub Delete_non_used_Loc()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Acell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim col As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim colName As String

'Value for deleting blanks
Dim DelTerm As Range
Set ws = Sheets("hello")
'This statement finds the Plan in the  column in the carrier report.
With ws
        Set Acell = .Range("A1:Z2").Find(What:="Plan 1", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
'If the plan column is found, then:
If Not Acell Is Nothing Then
    col = Acell.Column
    colName = Split(.Cells(, col).address, "$")(1)
    Lastrow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'This is the range of rows in the column specified (Plan 1).
    Set rng = .Range(colName & "2:" & colName & Lastrow)
'Finds and deletes terminated employees by searching for blanks via the Plan 1 column.
 Do
    Set DelTerm = rng.Find("", LookIn:=xlValues) 'Finds the blanks.
    If Not DelTerm Is Nothing Then DelTerm.EntireRow.Delete 'Deletes the row     where blanks are found.
Loop While Not DelTerm Is Nothing
Else
    MsgBox "Could not delete blank employees!"
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**
A little bit more challenging, but definitely still do-able! To maintain those "Random Data Fields", we will take advantage of a `Collection` object that holds all the column numbers of interest (i.e. any column number containing the word "Plan").

By looping through the first row and building the `Collection`, we can later simply loop through the `Collection` and look only at the important cells.

The heavily-commented code below should do the trick.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DeleteBlankRowsRev2()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, lngIdx As Long
    Dim varColItem As Variant
    Dim blnAllBlank As Boolean
    Dim col As Collection
    Set col = New Collection

    'First things first: we identify our basic variables
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hello")

    With wks
        'Now that our sheet is defined, we'll find the last row and last column
        lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        lngLastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

        'Awesome! With the last row and column in our pocket, we now
        'know a lot about the data range we will be checking for blanks

        'Here we loop through the first row, adding any column number
        'that contains the word "plan"
        For lngIdx = 1 To lngLastCol
            If InStr(UCase(CStr(.Cells(1, lngIdx))), "PLAN") Then
                col.Add lngIdx
            End If
        Next lngIdx

        'Since we need to delete rows, we start from the bottom and move up
        For lngIdx = lngLastRow To 1 Step -1

            'Start by setting a flag to immediately stop checking
            'if a cell is NOT blank
            blnAllBlank = True

            'Loop through all the column numbers contained in our collection
            For Each varColItem In col

                'If the cell is NOT blank, change the flag to False
                'then exit this For loop
                If .Cells(lngIdx, CInt(varColItem)) <> "" Then
                    blnAllBlank = False
                End If
                If Not blnAllBlank Then Exit For
            Next varColItem

            'Delete the row if the blnBlank variable is True
            If blnAllBlank Then
                .Rows(lngIdx).Delete
            End If

        Next lngIdx
    End With

    'That's it -- we're done!
    MsgBox "Script complete!"

End Sub
```

**Original Answer**
The heavily-commented code below should do the trick.

In short, we:

1. Identify the range of plan data
2. Loop through the range BACKWARDS
3. For each row, if every cell in the space defined in #1 above is empty delete the row

And don't forget to celebrate!

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DeleteBlankRows()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, lngIdx As Long, _
        lngColCounter As Long
    Dim blnAllBlank As Boolean

    'First things first: we identify our basic variables
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hello")

    With wks
        'Now that our sheet is defined, we'll find the last row and last column
        lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        lngLastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

        'Awesome! With the last row and column in our pocket, we can
        'loop over the full range (whether it only has 2 columns or 4)

        'Since we need to delete rows, we start from the bottom and move up
        For lngIdx = lngLastRow To 1 Step -1

            'Start by setting a flag to immediately stop checking
            'if a cell is NOT blank and initializing the column counter
            blnAllBlank = True
            lngColCounter = 2

            'Check cells from left to right while the flag is True
            'and the we are within the farthest-right column
            While blnAllBlank And lngColCounter <= lngLastCol

                'If the cell is NOT blank, trip the flag and exit the loop
                If .Cells(lngIdx, lngColCounter) <> "" Then
                    blnAllBlank = False
                Else
                    lngColCounter = lngColCounter + 1
                End If

            Wend

            'Delete the row if the blnBlank variable is True
            If blnAllBlank Then
                .Rows(lngIdx).Delete
            End If

        Next lngIdx
    End With

    'That's it -- we're done!
    MsgBox "Script complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks so much for the answer, I'd love to celebrate. However, I should have specified that the "Plan" columns are not necessarily the only columns in the workbook. There may be some random columns spaced throughout the workbook. I've amended the picture to show what it could look like. I know the headers will always be called "Plan 1", "Plan 2" etc. but finding the last column won't work because the data in those columns isn't what I need to filter by. I suppose I could delete unused columns...

Comment: Hey @NLourme -- do those "Random Data" columns need to stick around, or can you delete them? If they can be deleted, the solution above could be modified with a quick loop that walks the columns (backwards, of course) and deletes columns not containing the string `Plan`

Comment: Hi @Dan Wagner, I could delete them though I would rather not. I run other macros and tests on those columns, so I would need to add them back in afterwards. One though I had was setting the values "Plan 1", "Plan 2" etc. in an array, and looping through those. Not sure if you think if thats feasible at all?

Comment: My answer above has been updated with an additional solution -- that should work!